# Adding a second filter without first one breaking in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a filter to replace the "true, false" return values with a "Yes or No".

In my filters.js file I have a dotNetDate filter that formats the date, I believe I am supposed to put my second filter in here but then my first one breaks and and views that used it are now non-viewable. If I comment out what I put in its viewable again, any help on how to add second filter without other one breaking?

```
angular.module('PCAFilters', []).filter('dotNetDate', function () {
return function (input) {
     return moment(input).format("M/D/YYYY");
  };
});

//angular.module('PCAFilters', []).filter('yesNo', function () {
//    return function (input) {
//        return input ? 'Yes' : 'No';
//    };
//});
```

Comment: can you post your HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
angular.module('PCAFilters', []).filter('dotNetDate', function () {
    return function (input) {
       return moment(input).format("M/D/YYYY");
    };
}).filter('yesNo', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    };
});
```

You were defining the module `PCAFilters` twice. If you want to get a module, leave off the `[]`, like this:

```
angular.module('PCAFilters').filter(...);
```

If you don't want to chain them together like I suggested, I would store the module in a local variable, instead of using `angular.module` for each filter definition. See below:

```
var filtersModule = angular.module('PCAFilters', []);

filtersModule.filter('dotNetDate', function () {
    return function (input) {
       return moment(input).format("M/D/YYYY");
    };
});

filtersModule.filter('yesNo', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    };
});
```